# Including functions with extern C linkage in library

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors, extern

I have included some C functions with extern c linkage in c++ code. E.g.

```
// File Y.cpp: 

extern C {  
 void fnA(void) { }  
 void fnB(void* a, void* b) { }  
}

class test {
....
};

// end of file
```

File Y is under module Mod. While building library libMod-O.a for module Mod, I don't see the functions under extern block included, unless Y.h is included in some other file (Mod.cpp) and the class test is used. So unless I create an object of test class in Mod.cpp, I do not see the extern functions (fnA, fnB) in the libMod-O.a, even through Y.cpp is compiled during build of libMod-O.a. The result of this is that linker error happens as another module uses fnA, fnB.

I do not see the connection between the extern functions fnA and fnB being included and usage of class test in Mod.cpp. Is this expected or is there a better way to define this?

Comment: It is good idea to move extern C declarations into h file. And include this h file wherever you use this external functions.

Comment: when you say 'i don't see the functions included' do you mean you used objdump or other method to view the archive contents or do you simply mean you get the linker errors?

Comment: you might have a link order problem where the files that use fnA come after the link of libMod-O.a but where Mod.cpp with object test comes before libMod-O.a so the obj file is pulled in before fnA/fnB are needed later. the gnu linker is a single pass linker by default.

Comment: Click on the link Thiago suggested and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean extern "C" of course.

You need to have a clean separation between your C code and your C++ code.

In YourCCode.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void fnA(void);
void fnB(void* a, void* b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In YourCCode.c:

```
void fnA(void) {}
void fnB(void* a, void* b) {}
```

Make sure your compiler compiles YourCCode.c as C, not as C++.

In your C++ code

```
#include "YourCCode.h"

fnA();
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

you might have a link order problem where the files that use fnA come after the link of libMod-O.a but where Mod.cpp with object test comes before libMod-O.a so the obj file is pulled in before fnA/fnB are needed later. the gnu linker is a single pass linker by default.

Comment: I did not use strings or objdump to look at symbols. I got linker error. libMod-O.a is the library for Mod.cpp too. Both Y.cpp and Mod.cpp are compiled into libMod-O.a. Otherwise, I'm not sure how creating an object of test in Mod.cpp solves the issue.

Comment: I just ran strings command and find fnA and fnB in libMod-O.a. But the link error still happens as class test is not used in Mod.cpp.